# Laying out a JTextField as wrappable JLabel - unwelcome behaviour

Tags: java, swing, layout, resize

I'm making a panel with three JTextAreas, each of which is an imitation of a wrappable JLabel. 
Here you have a sample code:

```
 public static String getLoremIpsumString() {
        return "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing "
                + "elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. "
                + "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip "
                + "ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate "
                + "velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat "
                + "non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frameMain = new JFrame(){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension prefDim = super.getPreferredSize();
                prefDim.width = 600;
                return prefDim;
            }
        };
        JPanel pnlMain = new JPanel();
        JTextArea txtAreaLeft = new JTextArea(getLoremIpsumString());
        JTextArea txtAreaRight = new JTextArea(getLoremIpsumString());
        JTextArea txtAreaBottom = new JTextArea(getLoremIpsumString());

        txtAreaLeft.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtAreaRight.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtAreaBottom.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtAreaLeft.setLineWrap(true);
        txtAreaRight.setLineWrap(true);
        txtAreaBottom.setLineWrap(true);
        txtAreaLeft.setEditable(false);
        txtAreaRight.setEditable(false);
        txtAreaBottom.setEditable(false);

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(pnlMain);
        pnlMain.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(txtAreaLeft)
                    .addComponent(txtAreaRight)
                )
                .addComponent(txtAreaBottom)
        );

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtAreaLeft)
                    .addComponent(txtAreaRight)
                )
                .addComponent(txtAreaBottom)
        );

        txtAreaLeft.setBackground(txtAreaLeft.getParent().getBackground());
        txtAreaRight.setBackground(txtAreaRight.getParent().getBackground());
        txtAreaBottom.setBackground(txtAreaBottom.getParent().getBackground());
        frameMain.setContentPane(pnlMain);
        frameMain.setVisible(true);
        frameMain.pack();
        frameMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

The image below shows the result:

[image]

And questions:
1) **What should I do in order to force that on the very beginning my frame looks like this:**

[image]

2) **After I change the frame's size to a bigger one (frame should be resizable), and then I try to get back to the smaller size, textboxes are not resized (do not become smaller). How should I fix that? I would like them to resize together with the frame resizing.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to Use GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html):

> The size of each component in a GroupLayout is constrained by three
>   values; minimum size, preferred size and maximum size. These sizes
>   control how the component resizes within the layout. The
>   GroupLayout.addComponent(...) method allows the size constraints to be
>   specified.

It seems you just need to specify these constrains on:

```
.addComponent(txtAreaLeft)
                    .addComponent(txtAreaRight)
                )
                .addComponent(txtAreaBottom)
```

and you'll be done.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I'll try. I thought that in this case I can rely on default settings... not a good approach ; )

Answer (score 1):

For future use: After elcodedocle's answer I modified a little bit the layout size details. Now it works:

The fixed main's code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frameMain = new JFrame(){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension prefDim = super.getPreferredSize();
                prefDim.width = 600;
                return prefDim;
            }
        };
        JPanel pnlMain = new JPanel();

        JTextArea txtAreaLeft = new JTextArea(getLoremIpsumString(), 10, 15);
        JTextArea txtAreaRight = new JTextArea(getLoremIpsumString(), 10, 15);
        JTextArea txtAreaBottom = new JTextArea(getLoremIpsumString(), 5, 15);

        txtAreaLeft.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtAreaRight.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtAreaBottom.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtAreaLeft.setLineWrap(true);
        txtAreaRight.setLineWrap(true);
        txtAreaBottom.setLineWrap(true);
        txtAreaLeft.setEditable(false);
        txtAreaRight.setEditable(false);
        txtAreaBottom.setEditable(false);

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(pnlMain);
        pnlMain.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(txtAreaLeft, 1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(txtAreaRight, 1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                )
                .addComponent(txtAreaBottom, 1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtAreaLeft)
                    .addComponent(txtAreaRight)
                )
                .addComponent(txtAreaBottom)
        );

        txtAreaLeft.setBackground(txtAreaLeft.getParent().getBackground());
        txtAreaRight.setBackground(txtAreaRight.getParent().getBackground());
        txtAreaBottom.setBackground(txtAreaBottom.getParent().getBackground());
        frameMain.setContentPane(pnlMain);
        frameMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameMain.pack();
        frameMain.setVisible(true);
    }
```